# Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/lipl245/WorldLeagueSyndicate/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-103: AAPT: error: resource string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID (aka com.worldleaguesyndicate:string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID) not found.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there a package or something that requires you to add a `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` as a string resource.

If you have the app id, you can add it to android/app/src/main/res/values/string.xml by adding

```
<string name="FACEBOOK_APP_ID">app_id_here</string>
```

inside the resources tag.

If you don't have it, you can look for that package and remove it. Also check your `AndroidManifest.xml` to be sure you don't have instances of `string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID`